# Github reversing direction of merge in pull request

Tags: git, github

I have two branches, a `development` branch and a `release` branch. I made some changes in the release branch that I now want to merge back into the development branch.

After creating a pull request on Github, and resolving all conflicts, I noticed that it actually merged `development` into `release`, essentially reversing the direction of the merge that I want. This is not the behaviour I want, as there are many commits and development that I don't want in my release branch.

Why is it doing this? How can I make sure that I only merge `release` into `development` and not the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Did you resolve the conflicts "online" with GitHub? It needs to record the resolved conflicts somewhere and that is going to be the source branch.

*Pull requests* should be used to re-integrate features or bugfixes into the mainline, not to sync the mainline back to the feature branch. For that you should merge locally and push your branch again, your rebase your branch on top of mainline (`release` in your case) – depending on your workflow.

Comment: I've tried both online and through command line. Both exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: If you run `git checkout development; git merge release` and resolve conflicts, the commit will be done on development.